# what is use of common abi in system call table

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I have added a simple system call which prints hello world using printk. For this, I added the below line to syscall_64.tbl

```
434     common  hello                   __x64_sys_hello
```

Wrote a simple application, which calls the system call from user space

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    long return_value = syscall(434);

    printf("return value from syscall: %ld\n", return_value);
    return 0;
}
```

It works and the dmesg is added with "Hello World" string

When i generate a 32-bit application by adding '-m32' flag, it fails with -ENOSYS

```
syscall_0x1b2(0x5663bfd0, 0xffb09a8c, 0x5663a5a4, 0x1, 0xffb09a84, 0xffb09a8c) = -1 (errno 38)
```

What is the use of "common" field in the second column of system call table. Do we need to declare again in 32-bit system call table to be accessible for 32-bit applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two 32-bit ABIs that can be supported by 64-bit x86 kernels, in addition to the native **x86-64** ABI. The 32-bit ABIs are:

1. The **i386** ABI that emulates the ABI implemented by 32-bit x86 kernels.
2. The **x32** ABI that is a newer 32-bit ABI for x86-64 kernels.

The GCC `-m32` flag will generate code for the i386 ABI. Use the `-mx32` flag to generate code for the x32 ABI.

The "syscall_64.tbl" file enumerates the system calls for the x86-64 and x32 ABIs:

1. The "64" entries are for the x64-64 ABI.
2. The "x32" entries are for the x32 ABI.
3. The "common" entries are for both the x64-64 and x32 ABI.

The "syscall_32.tbl" enumerates the system calls for the i386 ABI. For each system call number, the table lists two entry points:

1. The entry point for 32-bit x86 kernels.
2. The "compat" entry point for i386 ABI emulation on x86-64 kernels.

Some obsolete system calls that are no longer implemented by the kernel are listed without an entry point.

While there is a lot of old, 32-bit binary-only software that uses the i386 ABI and runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, the newer x32 ABI never became very popular. Applications using the x32 ABI won't run on systems with 32-bit kernels.